# Difference between complex matrix multiplication in matlab and python

Tags: python, matlab, matrix-multiplication, translate, complex-numbers

I'm trying to translate a program from matlab to python and I don't get one piece to work.
In this line of the code I'm trying to multiply 2 complex arrays:

Matlab:
`Croco2=refAntDiag_norm'*testAntDiag_norm;`

Python:
`Croco2 = np.matmul(refAntDiag_norm.transpose(), testAntDiag_norm))`

But the Outputs are different.

Does anybody have an idea on how to fix this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In MATLAB, this operator: `'` is the [complex conjugate transpose](https://uk.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/ctranspose.html), not just a normal transpose which numpy's [.transpose()](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.transpose.html) is doing.

MATLAB's [transpose operator](https://uk.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/transpose.html) is `.'`.

So the MATLAB code equivalent to what you have in Python would be

```
Croco2=refAntDiag_norm.'*testAntDiag_norm;
```

From the docs, it looks like the numpy equivalent for the complex conjugate transpose is [`.H`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.matrix.H.html).